# Should i use Application Insights or AppCenter Diagnostics for Cordova Apps

Tags: cordova, azure-application-insights, visual-studio-app-center

Both Application Insights and AppCenter Diagnostics allow monitoring of Cordova Apps following these links:

https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-plugin-ms-appinsights

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/appcenter/sdk/getting-started/cordova

Given that the GitHub Repo is a bit outdated, i suppose AppCenter is now the suggested way to monitor Apps. 
However, AppCenter doesn't provide end-to-end monitoring capabilitys when using Azure Services in the Backend.

- So, when making a decision, which monitoring system to use for our Cordova Apps, should we base the decision on the following question?

  1. Using Azure Services with AppInsights in the Backend? -> Use
     Application Insights for the Cordova Frontend.
  2. Having a Standalone App or no Azure Backend -> Use AppCenter Diagnostics.
- Are there other thinks to take into account?
- Is AppCenter Diagnostics providing any other benefit i would not get from AppInsights?

PS: I know about the possibility to send AppCenter Diagnostics data to AppInsights, however this is just a data export and lacks end-to-end capabilitys.

Comment: (from Application Insights team) Referenced GitHub Repo is not officially supported (version 0.0.2 is another pointer towards it). Though it might just work.

Comment: @ZakiMa Thank you for the feedback. So there are no plans to expand Application Insights usage scenarios to cover Apps as well? Should we stick with AppCenter's limited functionality for Apps? Just trying to give guidance to our devs for monitoring in different application types.

Comment: Forwarded this thread to App Insights Usage team. They should respond soon with guidance.

Comment: @ZakiMa any updates on this?

Comment: This is probably a pretty opinion based question so i'm not sure why nobody closed it yet.  I've also forwarded to the AppCenter team.  but I've also added my opinion answer below.

Answer (score 4):

In general, I believe the guidance is "if it is a mobile app, use AppCenter".
you can then set up that AppCenter app to export to application insights:

https://blog.xamarin.com/appcenter-continuous-export-application-insights/

That way you get appcenter's device support/other features, AND you get application insight's tools/features/etc on that same data.  This is especially useful if you already use application insights for server side telemetry.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However, exporting AppCenter's diagnostics doesn't give me both features. It's just an export of the data to AppInsights to allow analysis of the data in the same place but it's lacking end-to-end correlation of requests the way AppInsights would give me. I would have to correlate data on my own. And that's why it's not a matter of opinion.

Comment: if that's the case, then you need to work with the appcenter team to make sure they either set, or allow *you* to set operationIds and other correlation values properly so it can work that way.

Comment: I started using AppCenter to send custom events from my mobile apps but I was quickly confronted to the limitation of the "tracing" [features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/analytics/xamarin#custom-events): 256 chars length for event names (that's ok); 125 chars length for properties values for each event whereas [Insights trace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/data-model-trace-telemetry) messages can hold far more data. For a mobile application maybe it's not needed to send big payloads but I found the AppCenter message size limit to low.

Answer (score 0):

there is this JavaScript SDK
[Github official link here](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS)https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS

this helps any JS application be-it React or Angular or Vue to log insights to AppInsights directly